# How do I bind DisplayMember of combobox as Multibind, a combinaiton of two properties

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, selecteditem

I have a combobox bound to

```
list<Tuple<Myobj1,MyObj2>>
```

I am here trying to find if we can tell combobox by some means that display member is MyObj1.Prop1 concatenated with MyObj2.Prop2

I cant find a direct way to do it, can do it with converters and ways but want to know if we can bind displaymemberPath somehow ?

thanks

Comment: would appreciate If I get reason for down vote really, I might be able to frame it in more understandable way for you ..

Answer (score -1):

I'd use a keyvalue pair

```
    List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> Foo = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        Foo.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("bar", 1));
        var bar = Foo[0].Key;
        var intOne = Foo[0].Value;
    }
```

Comment: and what do I bind to combobox then ?

Comment: the list of KeyValuePairs .. so comboBox.Datasource = foo;

Comment: Quesiton is about DisplayMember not itemsSource :-s